# Не могу сделать описание команды консольного приложения

Tags: php, yii2, консоль

В общем, создал контроллер команды, при вызове приложения yii2 из консоли, команда отображается как положено, но не знаю как прописать, что делает команда. 
Нужно как краткое описание сделать, так и при вызове help <команда>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить методы `getActionHelp(yii\base\Action $action)` и `getActionHelpSummary(yii\base\Action $action)` для возврата полной и краткой справки соответственно. По умолчанию эти методы должны возвращать полный PHPDoc и его первую строчку соответственно.

Comment: Гениально, подсказал куда копать. Переопределил getHelpSummary - Короткая подсказка к контроллеру. Спасибо !!.

Comment: Верно, только type hinting там нет.